# How to send PHP input stream data using curl?

Tags: php, curl, command-line-interface

### POST

On my local machine, I want to use **cURL** as an HTTP client like so:

```sh
curl -X POST -F 'email=derp@example.com' -F 'password=blink182' http://example.com
```

The above curl statement uses the HTTP POST method which can be retrieved in PHP like so:

```php
echo $_POST['email'];       // derp@example.com
echo $_POST['password'];    // blink182
```

### php://input

However, what I really wanted is the data from the [PHP input stream](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input)  `php:://input` and not from the [POST method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) `$_POST`.

The PHP input stream can be retrieved in PHP like so:

```php
$input = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'php://input' ) );
echo $input->email;     // derp@example.com
echo $input->password;  // blink182
```

Which brings me to my question, how to send PHP input stream data using curl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [PHP website](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input):

> `php://input` is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body. `php://input` is not available with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

So if you specify the `Content-Type` as `application/json`  using `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` you ought to get it in the input stream

complete example:

```bash
curl -X POST https://reqbin.com/echo/post/json
   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
   -d {\"email\":\"derp@example.com\",\"password\":\"blink182\"}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion like so:
`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" 'email=derp@example.com' -F 'password=blink182' http://example.com` but didn't quite work.

Comment: ah you also need to send the actual json - curl won't convert the form fields into json for you. I have added an example to my answer